# É possível enviar push notification no Android com aplicação web em HTTP

Tags: javascript, android

É possível autorizar envio de notificações de uma aplicação web em HTTP no Android?

Desenvolvo para uma aplicação web interna que acessamos por HTTP e estava estudando como enviar notificações push para os smartphones dos usuários, porém na parte `Notification.permission` sempre cai no `denied`, o Chrome no Android do usuário sequer permite enviar o pop-up de solicitar permissão com o `Notification.requestPermission()`. Eu já sei que quando a `Notification.permission` está `denied` não é mais permitido enviar requisição de permissão, porém nem pegando o cel e tentando aprovar na mão eu consigo autorizar.

Li em alguns lugares que tem a ver com o HTTP, que o próprio Android não permite notificações vindas de sites HTTP. Mas as informações que li estavam um pouco incompletas. É realmente **impossível** enviar notificações num site HTTP? A única saída é usar HTTPS? Ou existe algum outro macete?